# Rendering Exception infomation on same page on a GET request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

If a HTTP GET action method throws an error and I handle that error with a class that inherits from HandleErrorAttribute, is there any way to return the same View that caused the exception with the HandleErrorInfo information?

I basically want to display error information on the same page that caused it on the top, similar to what I could do with a POST request.

How would I set the result of filterContext to do such a thing?

Here is the implementation of my error handling class:

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        HandleErrorInfo model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"], (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]);

        // How do I pass the model back to the calling View which threw the error?

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(filterContext.RouteData.Values));
    }
```

Then I'd like to be able to access the model from the calling View. Can I use TempData or ViewData or is that considered bad practice?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code (handlerErrorAttribute). Normally the error handling is handled in your front end code.

Comment: I added code to the original post.

Comment: "How do I pass the model back to the calling View which threw the error?" I don't really think you can because your model will inherently be of a different structure than your view expects. You can do one of 2 things return an error code to your requesting call or look into handeling errors on front end code.